# Python CSV Writer trimming leading zeros

Tags: python, csv, python-2.7

I am reading in a csv file in python, changing a few values, and writing it back out. I read in the file using:

```
bomReader = csv.reader( open( args.filename, 'rb' ), delimiter=',' )
for row in bomReader:
    #do stuff
```

One of the fields contains values such as `0406`, where the leading zero is important. After reading the csv file, if I print this field using say `print row[2]`, it displays correctly with the leading 0.

When I write this back in to my new csv file however, the output has no leading zero. I assume this is because it is considered to be an int and the leading zero is trimmed. As I can't use format specifiers in the csv.writer writeRow() function, what is the correct way to prevent this behaviour?

Code:

```
bomReader = csv.reader( open( args.filename, 'rb' ), delimiter=',' )
bomWriter = csv.writer(open(outfile, 'wb'), delimiter=',', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

for row in bomReader:
try:
    qty = int(row[3])
    if (qty > 0):
        cs = row[4].split(';')
        for each in cs:
            bomWriter.writerow([row[0],row[1], row[2],'1',each.strip(),row[5],row[6],row[7],row[8],row[9]])
    elif (qty == 0):
        print "Deleted line"
    else:
        bomWriter.writerow(row)
except ValueError:
        bomWriter.writerow(row)
```

Sample row from the input csv file:

```
1007,C,0406,2,C456;C219,ANY,,,,,,
```

Rows in output csv file:

```
1007,C,406,1,C456,ANY,,,,
1007,C,406,1,C219,ANY,,,,
```

Comment: `csv` module ignores whether something *could be* `int` and sees everything as strings. Can you post your entire relevant code?

Comment: Added. The field in question that is losing its leading zero is row[2]

Comment: will you please provide the csv data so we can create same problem in our system?

Comment: check that there is no `row[2] = int(row[2])`. The code might be simpler if you `row[3] = '1'; row[4] = each.strip()` and always use `.writerow(row)`. Also `each` is not very descriptive name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The codes you supplied are working correctly as you want under `Python 2.6.7` and `Python 2.7.2`, `csv.__version=='1.0'`. Output:

```
1007,C,0406,1,C456,ANY,,,,
1007,C,0406,1,C219,ANY,,,,
```